# как убрать уведомление на android которое нельзя скрыть

Tags: android

У меня на телефоне стоит уведомление которое нельзя убрать и оно бесит!
[image: Уведомление Tele2 Меню]

И его нельзя убрать даже через настройки

[image: Настройки]

Каким образом его убрать?

Comment: А если тыкнуть на уведомление и держать несколько секунд пока не появится настройка, а там выбрать не показывать

Comment: @gil9red Там нету "Не показывать" (фото 2)

Comment: можно прибить приложение и тогда уведомление должно пропасть

Comment: У меня, на месте уведомления показывается небольшое меню. Возможно, разные версии ОС + разные прошивки. Наглядно: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Aqj.jpg и https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZxUR.jpg

Comment: Некоторые системные уведомления в Андроиде не скрываются. Например, у меня (и на многих других телефонах которые я видел) не пропадает уведомление о том, что подключен виртуальный номер (это предоставляется настройками сети, приложение SIM Toolkit). Телефон Pixel 3a с чистой прошивкой Андроид 10.

Comment: Могу предложить радикальное решение -- удалить приложение SIM Toolkit :) Сделать это можно без рута на телефоне: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/181557/how-to-remove-the-sim-toolkit-from-my-phone-without-root-or-flashing-any-rom